# Got an import error all of a sudden

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv

So I set up a virtualenv on Ubuntu, installed everything, and got the development site running with `runserver`. All my own unit tests passed, but many of the Django packages' unit tests were not passing.

So I tried doing `git bisect` to figure this out, checking out the very earliest commits I had made. I went too early in history, back when the development environment was using different database engines, packages, etc., and the site of course couldn't run. I then decided to work on something else more important than failing Django unit tests (since my own were working), and so I went back to the latest commit in the development branch.

I fired up `runserver` again, but this time when I reloaded the homepage, I was met with the error:

```
Traceback:
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "...project dir.../myproject/urls.py" in <module>
  2. import frontpage.views

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named views
```

Everything was working just fine before I tried the git bisect. But not any more, at least on my local machine.

So I googled around, and changed my `ROOT_URLCONF` from `'myproject.urls'` to just `'urls'`. Now I get this error message:

```
Traceback:
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "...venv.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named urls
```

I googled some more and thought maybe my Python path didn't include my project directory... but no, it totally does when I included a `print sys.path` in my `settings.py` file for the project!

So what's the problem here? I am using Django 1.4.3, and starting the server using `python manage.py runserver`. I swear my website was working just a few hours ago, and I've since done `git checkout development` and `git reset` many times... I've tried deleting the virtualenv, recreating it, and reinstalling all the Python packages. I'm still getting the same error.

(Also, I did activate the virtualenv, and I've even tried restarting, just in case... no luck so far)

**UPDATE**

Following Lennart's suggestion, I started the debugger right before the failing import, and found that `import frontpage` works, but not `import frontpage.views`, `frontpage.tests`, or anything else. I do have an `__init__.py` file in the `frontpage` directory as well. At this point, `sys.path` contains my project folder all right...

I have already been including `frontpage` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` as well.

**FIXED**

Thanks to Lennart, I checked that the `frontpage` module was indeed getting imported correctly. The correct `.pyc` file was shown, but this made me wonder if the pyc files were somehow out of sync with my actual code.

So I deleted all the pyc files, restarted the server, and everything is working fine once more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you get ImportErrors because the module you try to import encounters some problem. For example maybe `frontpage.view` is trying to import a module that has a SyntaxError. The best way to figure out exactly what is going on is to put an `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` just before the failing import and try to `s`tep inside the import.

Also make sure that when you import `frontpage` that you get the module back you expect, check specifically the modules `__file__` attribute, and that it is the `__init__.pyc` you expect.

Comment: I've updated my question, not sure exactly what to try looking at next. Any ideas?

Comment: and my site worked before, and is still working on the development server, with the same exact code. I've checked the file again too; no syntax errors detected.