# ImportError: No module named 3530

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

Can someone explain me why is my form returning this error `ImportError: No module named 3530`. I see that this occur in `get_success_url`, but I can not understand what does `ImportError` having to do with this.
I have a static form which return some data and displayed it in a template, so this is the `FormView`

```
import calendar
import datetime

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .helpers.user_util import get_user_full_name_or_user_name
from models import Rate
from statistics.forms import CommissionsMonthSelectionForm
from statistics.services import ManagerCommissionsProjectsCalculation, CommissionsAccessService


class UserSalesCommissionsView(FormView):
    template_name = "statistics/user_sales_commissions.html"
    form_class = CommissionsMonthSelectionForm
    currency = Rate.EUR

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        requesting_user = request.user
        if CommissionsAccessService.can_view_commissions_page(requesting_user, user_id):
            month = int(self.request.GET.get('month', datetime.datetime.now().month))
            year = int(self.request.GET.get('year', datetime.datetime.now().year))
            form = CommissionsMonthSelectionForm(initial={'year': year, 'month': month})
            context_data = self.get_context_data(user_id, month, year, form=form)
            return self.render_to_response(context_data)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden('Access denied')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        requesting_user = self.request.user

        if CommissionsAccessService.can_view_commissions_page(requesting_user, user_id):
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            if form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(form, user_id)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden('Access denied')

    def form_valid(self, form, user_id=None):
        year = form.cleaned_data['year']
        month = form.cleaned_data['month']
        return redirect(self.get_success_url(user_id, month, year))

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                             "Invalid data. Please check fields.")
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form)
        )

    def get_success_url(self,
                        user_id=None,
                        year=datetime.datetime.now().year,
                        month=datetime.datetime.now().month):
        return reverse("vinclucms_statistics:manager_commissions_statistics", user_id) + \
               "?month=" + str(month) + "&year=" + str(year)

    def get_context_data(self,
                         user_id=None,
                         year=datetime.datetime.now().year,
                         month=datetime.datetime.now().month,
                         **kwargs):
        context = super(UserSalesCommissionsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_name'] = get_user_full_name_or_user_name(get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id))
        context['can_view'] = True
        context['currency'] = self.currency
        context['month'] = calendar.month_name[month]
        context['year'] = year

        context['commissions'] = ManagerCommissionsProjectsCalculation.get_project_list(
            self.currency, year, month, user_id)
        return context
```

and this full [Traceback](http://dpaste.com/0ZSD6M1),

form:

```
from django import forms

from statistics.choices import StatisticsChoices


class CommissionsMonthSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=StatisticsChoices.YEAR_CHOICES)
    month = forms.ChoiceField(choices=StatisticsChoices.MONTH_CHOICES)
```

url:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
         login_required(views.SupplierInvoiceStatisticsView.as_view()),
          name='supplier_invoice_statistics'),
         url(r'^statistics/commissions/sales/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$',
)
```

Comment: Nope this is all ready checked, I have saw this and checked it

Comment: In that case I'll defer to someone more well versed in Django... although you may wish to include the information from that question to show that isn't your problem.

Comment: Can you show us your complete list of url patterns, rather than just the one you've provided? That should help convince us that it's not that you missed the `patterns` constructor.

Comment: I have updated the `url` part

Comment: It still doesn't look right though... the indentation is confusing and also the brackets don't add up in a sensible way. Are you sure that's what you're using?

Comment: The last code snippet (`urlpatterns`) seems incorrect.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to attempt the fix [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472132/got-an-import-error-all-of-a-sudden) and rebuild your `.pyc` files.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, thanks for the suggestion that did it